# How to move emails

Tags: outlook.com

Yesterday, I somehow moved all emails from my inbox to my delete box.  They have not been deleted! Can someone tell me how I can move them back to the inbox?  Maybe a large chunk of them at a time.

Comment: Select all the emails then move the emails back to the inbox.  How you select an email, within hotmail client within a browser, is documented on Microsoft's website.

Comment: @Ramhound: Actually, it's not. Outlook.com documentation is surprisingly lacking. If there is documentation, it's not easily findable from outlook.com.

Answer (score 1):

When you select the "Deleted items" folder, there is either at the top or the bottom (depending on the version of the web interface) a button that says "Recover" or "Recover deleted messages"

Source: [Outlook.com manual](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Restore-deleted-email-messages-in-Outlook-com-cf06ab1b-ae0b-418c-a4d9-4e895f83ed50)

Comment: "Recover deleted messages" is for when you actually delete them. (I think)  My messages are NOT deleted, they are sitting in the delete folder

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't choose more than a page at a time to act on. (See [this answer from answers.microsoft.com](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/oemail-ofolders/how-to-select-all-mail-from-a-folder-at-outlookcom/9bba634e-bd7b-42f0-a88b-c9aca24c41b3).)

To select all of the messages on a page, click the checkbox at the top of the list (next to the "View" menu, which defaults to "All").

Open the "Move to" menu at the top of the page, and select "Inbox".

Repeat as needed.

Most likely you used the "[sweep](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Organize-your-Inbox-in-Outlook-com-19eee6b9-09a1-4db6-b5d6-37644190884f)" feature, which makes it easy to get rid of messages you don't want, but if you're not careful you may move more than you intended.